# How to search file name just created by some one on Linux server

Tags: linux, grep

How to search multiple files which has been created.

I'll try to explain my problem as best as I can, but please pardon my English .. What I'm trying to do, seemed simple enough to me, however every solution I've found so far just won't work. I wanna to find how many *.tar file created today by some of my friends .

Comment: Assuming that you have access to their directories, `find /path1 /path2  -mtime -1 -name \*tar` should work. If your friends restrict access to their directories you may be out of luck. Having `sudo` access will help but you can still be blocked if the paths are on NFS shares.

Comment: Hello - just following up on this: did doneal's comment or my answer clarify things for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want today as in after midnight, this should work (not DST safe!):

```
find /path/to/directory -name \*.tar -mmin "-$(( $(date "+10#%H * 60 + 10#%M") ))"
```

The time calculation shamelessly snaffled from this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30374251/1394729) ;)

Of course, if your friends chose to tar & compress things `*.tar` may not find what you're looking for. It could be any of `*.tar.gz`, `*.tgz`, `*.tar.bz2`, `*.tbz`, `*.t...`, for all supported compression algorithms. If your friends are super-cheeky/naughty they could have used an arbitrary extension to confuse you.

Short of using `find /path/to/directory -mmin "-$(( $(date "+10#%H * 60 + 10#%M") ))" -print0| xargs -0 file` and some clever script you can't be too sure to find all tar files.